# Ansible: ERROR: Invalid requirement: \"u'woth': False

Tags: python, pip, ansible, devops

In this task I'm supposed to access a folder **~/Libs/lib** and install the last version of the pip packages found.

I have an error installing a pip package on local via ansible.

NB: The package is well installed outside ansible

my task

```
- name: Get latest lib version
  find:
    paths: "{{ lib_path }}"
    patterns: '*.whl'
  register: lib_wheels_file



- name: Get latest file
  set_fact:
    latest_file: "file:///{{ lib_wheels_file.files | sort(reverse=true) | first }}"
  become: yes


- name: Install lib
  pip: 
   name: '{{ latest_file }}'
  become: yes

 lib_path is found under ~/Libs
```

The error I get:

> ERROR: Invalid requirement: \"u'woth': False\"\n"

With -vvv option i got this output :

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "cmd": [
        "/usr/local/bin/pip2", 
        "install", 
        "file:///{u'uid': 1000", 
        " u'woth': False", 
        " u'mtime': 1571862393.0", 
        " u'inode': 11798916", 
        " u'isgid': False", 
        " u'size': 175829", 
        " u'roth': True", 
        " u'isuid': False", 
        " u'isreg': True", 
        " u'pw_name': u'tb62'", 
        " u'gid': 1000", 
        " u'ischr': False", 
        " u'wusr': True", 
        " u'xoth': False", 
        " u'islnk': False", 
        " u'nlink': 1", 
        " u'issock': False", 
        " u'rgrp': True", 
        " u'gr_name': u'tb62'", 
        " u'path': u'/home/tb62/Libs/lib/lib-1.4.0-py2-none-any.whl'", 
        " u'xusr': False", 
        " u'atime': 1575281633.538627", 
        " u'isdir': False", 
        " u'ctime': 1574842250.317574", 
        " u'wgrp': False", 
        " u'xgrp': False", 
        " u'dev': 2065", 
        " u'isblk': False", 
        " u'isfifo': False", 
        " u'mode': u'0644'", 
        " u'rusr': True}\""
    ], 
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "chdir": null, 
            "editable": false, 
            "executable": null, 
            "extra_args": null, 
            "name": [
                "file:///{u'uid': 1000", 
                " u'woth': False", 
                " u'mtime': 1571862393.0", 
                " u'inode': 11798916", 
                " u'isgid': False", 
                " u'size': 175829", 
                " u'roth': True", 
                " u'isuid': False", 
                " u'isreg': True", 
                " u'pw_name': u'tb62'", 
                " u'gid': 1000", 
                " u'ischr': False", 
                " u'wusr': True", 
                " u'xoth': False", 
                " u'islnk': False", 
                " u'nlink': 1", 
                " u'issock': False", 
                " u'rgrp': True", 
                " u'gr_name': u'tb62'", 
                " u'path': u'/home/tb62/Libs/lib/lib-1.4.0-py2-none-any.whl'", 
                " u'xusr': False", 
                " u'atime': 1575281633.538627", 
                " u'isdir': False", 
                " u'ctime': 1574842250.317574", 
                " u'wgrp': False", 
                " u'xgrp': False", 
                " u'dev': 2065", 
                " u'isblk': False", 
                " u'isfifo': False", 
                " u'mode': u'0644'", 
                " u'rusr': True}\""
            ], 
            "requirements": null, 
            "state": "present", 
            "umask": null, 
            "version": null, 
            "virtualenv": null, 
            "virtualenv_command": "virtualenv", 
            "virtualenv_python": null, 
            "virtualenv_site_packages": false
        }
    },
```

Comment: `lib_wheels_file.files` is not a list of strings (file names) but [a list of dictionaries](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/find_module.html#return-values) from which you have to extract `path` keys.

Comment: well, my need is to extract only the file name from the full path, any suggestions plz  ?

Comment: Try `{{ lib_wheels_file.files | sort(reverse=true) | first | attr('path') }}` or  `{{ lib_wheels_file.files | attr('path') | sort(reverse=true) | first }}`

Comment: regarding this solution `{{ lib_wheels_file.files | attr('path') | sort(reverse=true) | first | attr('path') }}`, i got The error was: 'list object' has no attribute 'path

Comment: That strange but I never fully understand Jinja. :-( IMO Ansible authors did a mistake and a disservice using Jinja instead of Python.

Comment: @phd : well i found the solution , i will share it in a new comment.
your comments helped me alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution i found is to map the attribute using map() function.

```
 - name: Get latest file   set_fact:
     latest_file: "{{ lib_wheels_file.files | map(attribute='path') | sort(reverse=true) | first }}"   become: yes
```